# How to do XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

I'm trying to use `AngularJS` within an POST request, but I cannot use `$scope` within the event.

Thats my code (for demonstration purpose I just add status within the Angular construct):

```
myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope) {
    $scope.myVal = [{status:"before (working)"}];

    doRequest(p1, p2, myCallback.bind(null, $scope));

    function myCallback($scope, a) {
        $scope.myVal = [{ status: a }];
    }

    function doRequest(p1, p2, callback) {
        $scope.myVal = [{ status: "prepare request (working)" }];

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://...";
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        //....
        xhr.send(myQuery);

        $scope.myVal = [{ status: "after post send (working)" }];
        callback("after post via callback (working)");

        //callback working till this point

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                callback("in event (NOT working)"); 
                //This is NOT working anymore (even this point is reached)!
            }
        };
    }
```

as added via comments in the code, the callback is working till the EventHandler assignment.

What I'm looking for is: How to use the callback (or more precise how to make `$scope` available/transfered in the event handler function)?

Comment: Use `$http` to make the request. You are trying to modify the scope in asynchronous code that is outside of angular context. When you do that angular needs to be told to run a digest to update the view. Using  `$http` takes care of that internally

Comment: For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass `$scope` into the `callback`, cause `$scope` is defined within the controller scope.

You may encounter into a problem when using "native" Ajax as you did, cause this operation is outside of `Angular` and angular doesn't know about, you need to make it familiar with Angular with [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

If you need to make a shortcut, Angular did it for you with the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

You can replace the entire `XMLHttpRequest` with injecting $http and calling `.post` method:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myVal = [{status:"before (working)"}];

    doRequest(p1, p2);

    function doRequest(p1, p2) {
        $scope.myVal = [{ status: "prepare request (working)" }];
        $http.post(url, myQuery).then(() => {
           $scope.myVal = [{ status: 'Finished' }]; // $scope is available here
        });
    }
}
```